# least_square does not run, residual is less than variables

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I'm using `scipy.optimize.least_square` to try to minimize the residual of function.

Here is the code:

```
def solido_3parameters(time, strain0, eta1, time0, stiffness2, eta):
    return strain0 + (sigma0 / eta1) * (time-time0) + sigma0 / stiffness2 * (1 - np.exp(-(time time0) * stiffness2/eta))

def residual(parameters):

    strain0 = parameters[0]
    eta1 = parameters[1]
    time0 = parameters[2]
    stiffness2 = parameters[3]
    eta = parameters[4]
    strain_fitted = solido_3parameters(time, strain0, eta1, time0, stiffness2, eta)

    RSS = np.sum(np.square(strain - strain_fitted))

    return RSS

initial_params = [1.0, 2, 1.5, 1.0, 1.0]

leastsq(residual, x0=initial_params)
```

But I got this error message:

```
TypeError: Improper input: func input vector length N=5 must not exceed func output vector length M=1.
```

What could the problem be? I tried to read the source code, but I didn't find the possible reason for this error.

Comment: As the error message is trying to tell you, `residual` takes a vector of size 5 but only returns a scalar. I cannot provide more help than that because your code has a syntax (error `time time0`) and undefined values: `sigma0`, `time`, and `strain`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some part of the code you shared that are not working.
For instance, in your function

```
def solido_3parameters(time, strain0, eta1, time0, stiffness2, eta):
    return strain0 + (sigma0 / eta1) * (time-time0) + sigma0 / stiffness2 * (1 - np.exp(-(time time0) * stiffness2/eta))
```

`sigma0` is undefined and `np.exp(-(time time0)` is not a valid expression.

But since you got the error message `TypeError: Improper input: func input vector length N=5 must not exceed func output vector length M=1.`, you must have a working code on your side.

Working with that, the first correction is with Scipy, you should be importing `scipy.optimize.leastsq` and not `scipy.optimize.least_square` since you want to use the function `leastsq()`

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
```

And the reason why you get an error is that the function you pass to `leastsq()` must return the same amount (or more) of point as the parameter. Since you pass 5 parameters you must return an array of 5 numbers or more.

For example, this code will not throw an error:

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import numpy as np


def solido_3parameters(time, strain0, eta1, time0, stiffness2, eta):
    sigma0 = 0
    return strain0 + (sigma0 / eta1) * (time-time0) + sigma0 / stiffness2 * (1 - np.exp(-(time - time0) * stiffness2/eta))

def residual(parameters):

    strain0 = parameters[0]
    eta1 = parameters[1]
    time0 = parameters[2]
    stiffness2 = parameters[3]
    eta = parameters[4]
    time = 0
    strain_fitted = solido_3parameters(time, strain0, eta1, time0, stiffness2, eta)
    strain = 0
    RSS = np.sum(np.square(strain - strain_fitted))
    
    return [RSS, 0, 0, 0, 0]

initial_params = [1.0, 2, 1.5, 1.0, 1.0]

leastsq_result = leastsq(residual, x0=initial_params)
print(leastsq_result)
```